# jQuery Check Radio Button: Why does it have to be done THIS way

Tags: jquery

This is my Radio Button:

```
<input type="radio" name="mode" id="mode_add" checked="checked" />ADD
<input type="radio" name="mode" id="mode_del" />DEL
```

I'm now learning jQuery, and for this, I'm changing the test for the state of the radio button from

```
// Test whether DEL is checked.
if(document.getElementById('mode_del').checked) { ... }
```

to jQuery. My first attempt failed, but I don't understand why:

```
// VARIATION 1 - THIS DOES NOT WORK (always false):
if($('#mode_del').attr('checked')) { ... }
```

Next, I googled a solution which works, but I don't understand why:

```
// VARIATION 2 - THIS WORKS
if($('#mode_del').is(':checked')) { ... }
```

Finally, I found in the jQuery documentation an explanation, which works AND which I understood:

```
// VARIATION 3 - THIS WORKS TOO
if($('#mode_del:checked').val()) { ... }
```

Of course, as for my application, I'm happy with what I have, but to satisfy my curiosity:

(A) Is it correct, that with my first solution, I only queried that the HTML element has an attribute named "checked", but this has nothing to do with the fact whether or not the user had selected the radio button?

(B) Why does solution 2 work? I didn't find a documentation for the "is" function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the documentation: [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/).

Globaly, `.is()` return true if the selector (in your case `':checked'`) is satisfied by *at least one of these elements* (elements returned by the selector).

**Quote**: ***Description:** Check the current matched set of elements against a selector, element, or jQuery object and return true if at least one of these elements matches the given arguments.*

Answer (score 3):

In the same jQuery documentation, it's explained:

`To retrieve and change DOM properties such as the checked, selected, or disabled state of form elements, use the .prop() method`.

The difference between attribute and properties is this:

HTML attribute corresponds to the HTML file- which is static- and property value corresponds to the DOM - which is dynamic.

For example, when the user types a value into the textbox, the attribute doesn't change., it will be the default vale always ( That explains why mode_del attribute is shown always as false ).

But the property changes.

```
<input type="radio" name="mode" id="mode_del" />DEL
```

Here by default, both the attribute `checked` and property `checked` are false. But, when the user clicks on the radio, it's property will change, but attribute does not.

Hence, better use `prop()` method to retrieve values for checkbox, value in a text box, etc. As mentioned clearly in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

Comment: This is the answer. I believe this change started in 1.8.2.

Comment: The change is since jQuery 1.6

Comment: After reading the docs, I now see that prop('checked') works (indeed, it does), and the example also mentions, that is(':checked') works too. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, here is the documentation for [is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

Secondly, for your jquery variation 1 to work, checked if the input's attribute `checked` is equal to the text `"checked"`

```
// VARIATION 1 - THIS DOES NOT WORK (always false):
if($('#mode_del').attr('checked') == 'checked') { ... }
```